# Williams - Probability with martingales book question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Chapter $0$ he defines a generating function as:

$$f(\theta) := E(\theta^X)=\sum_{k \in Z^+} \theta^k P(X=k)$$

Fair enough, I follow that.

We then on the $3$ page have:

$f(\theta):=E(\theta^{Z_n})=\sum \theta^k P(Z_n = k)$, I find that $Z_n$ as the power of $\theta$ a bit disturbing.. but since it is a definition I guess I don't have to make any sense of it?

I am then completely lost here, same page:

$f_{n+1}(\theta)=f_n (f(\theta))$. Naturally I look at each side individually in the perspective of the formula above this one:

$f_{n+1}(\theta) = E(\theta^{Z_{n+1}}) = \sum \theta^k P(Z_{n+1} = k)$
But when I look at the RHS: $f_n(f(\theta))=E(f(\theta)^{Z_n})=\sum f(\theta)^k P(Z_n=k)$. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: You got the first definition wrong, the correct formula is $$f(\theta)=E(\theta^X)=\sum_k\theta^kP(X=k),$$ which is just the usual formula of the expectation of a function of a (discrete) random variable $$E(g(X))=\sum_kg(k)P(X=k).$$ Each other formula in your post is similar. ("since it is a definition I guess I don't have to make any sense of it?"... Well!)

Comment: the reason I said that is because I do not understand what $Z_n$ is doing in the power there

Comment: Actually. I did not understand it because I got the formula wrong. Now I do. But I still don't understand that later part